# SQL syntax showing date

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get my article to fetch how many comments it has, and display the number. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$amount_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['articleid']) . "'"); 
$comments = mysql_num_rows($amount_get);

$grab = mysql_query("SELECT id, news_title, news_content, news_date, news_author FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($grab)){
?>


<div class="pane">
    <li>               
        <h2><?php echo $row['news_title'] ?></h2>
        <div class="meta">
            <span class="color"> &bull; </span>
            <?php echo $row['news_date'] ?>
            <span class="color"> &bull; </span>
          </div>

          Comments: <?php echo $comments ?>
```

but for some reason, it stays on "0". This is what it looks like: [image]

and my columns are id, articleid,name,comment,date & ip.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Jeremy1026 - The question is basically "Why does `mysql_num_rows()` return zero?"

Comment: Are you certain articles.id matches comments.id? That would imply only a single comment would be allowed per article max. You need to look up what the relationship between the table are.

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause is looking for id = articleid.

What you want is where articleid = articleid.

```
$amount_get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE articleid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['articleid']) . "'");
```

Comment: Hey Kyle, thanks for the help. But It still shows zero for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the SQL is faulty. Check your articleid GET variable. Also should it not be doing a different query and mysql_num_rows for each article's comments as each article likely contains different number of comments.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  articles.id, news_title, news_content, news_date, news_author 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comment WHERE comment.id=articles.id) as comments
FROM articles 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

This will get you the first 5 articles and their related comment counts.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a single query.

```
$grab = mysql_query(
"SELECT a.id, a.news_title, a.news_content, a.news_date, a.news_author, count(*) as comment_count
FROM articles a 
LEFT JOIN comment c ON c.articleid = a.id 
ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 5 GROUP BY a.id");
```

Then instead of

```
Comments: <?php echo $comments ?>
```

Do:

```
Comments: <?php echo $row['comment_count']; ?>
```

Let me know if the query is working, I'm not sure if the Group by is correctly placed there.

Comment: I'm getting a boolean error: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/krissale/public_html/blog/index.php on line 32 on that line 32 would be `$comment = mysql_num_rows($comment_count);` @maltray

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in on line 40 still getting that error. on line 40 I have `?>` this is my full code: http://pastebin.com/PfRDmmCR @maltray